# How to convert 21/09/2009 to 2007-09-21 00:00:00.000 format in sql?

Tags: sql, datetime, varchar

How can I make this type of SQL Conversion:

I tried this: `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 21/09/2007, 131)`

Comment: `datetime` doesn't have a format. `datetime` constants are expressed in quotes, like: `'21/09/2007'`. `21/09/2007` is an expression, evaluating to `0`.

Comment: Better show some sample data and the expected result and let people here think how to do this. You should also tag your DBMS

Answer (score 1):

It seems that 131 is the wrong code.
I run the above and works fine:

`SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '21/09/2007', 103)`

You can see more details  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to convert 21/09/200**7** to 2007-09-21 00:00:00.000:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP('2007/09/21');
```

Comment: In sql server, which the code in the question suggests, `TIMESTAMP` is not a date/time datatype